# Unable to simulate Ctrl+S keydown in angular test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm new to Angular test and I want to automated test on my projects, now I have an event that accepts keydown event and I want to simulate it on my test.

```
 onKeyDown(event){
  let charCode = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
  if(event.ctrlKey && charCode = 's'){
    //other actions
    event.preventDefault();
  }
 }
```

my spec.ts

```
it('should press ctrl+s',()=>{
  const event = new KeyBoardEvent('keydown',{
    key: 'ctrlKey'
  });

 component.onKeyDown(event);
});
```

I don't know how to include the charCode 'S'

Answer (score 0):

You could create your `KeyboardEvent` like this:

```js
const eventInit: KeyboardEventInit = {
  key: 'S',
  ctrlKey: true
};
eventInit['keyCode'] = 83;

const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', eventInit);
```

Note that I had to use bracket notation to set the `keyCode` property because it's [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), so the typings for `KeyboardEventInit` wouldn't allow it to be added directly the way I did for `key` and `ctrlKey`.

The full test would look like this (assuming you're verifying that `preventDefault` gets called):

```js
it('should call preventDefault is Ctrl-S is pressed', () => {
  const eventInit: KeyboardEventInit = {
    key: 'S',
    ctrlKey: true
  };
  eventInit['keyCode'] = 83;

  const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', eventInit);

  const preventDefaultSpy = spyOn(event, 'preventDefault').and.stub();
  component.onKeyDown(event);

  expect(preventDefaultSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-demo-keydown-with-ctrl-key?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts) with a working version of this approach.

A couple notes about your app code, though:

1. In your `if` condition you have `charCode = 's'` (assignment) but you probably want it to be `charCode === 's'` (equality check).
2. [event.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is deprecated, so you might want to use something else on the event object instead, like [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).